# Ambiguity Error in WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-6

I am trying to create a simple WPF Project that takes in student details inputted through a textbox, then stores them into a student database once the add student button is clicked.

This was working fine and was storing in the database no problem

```
private void OnAddNewStudent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (db1104983Entities1 context = new db1104983Entities1()) //Contained within using so it automatically disposes when it is out of scope
    {
        Student student1 = new Student //creates new Student Object
        { 
            MatricNo= txtM.Text,
            FirstName = txt1.Text,
            LastName = txt2.Text,
            Component1 = txtcom1.Text,
            Component2 = txtcom2.Text,
            Component3 = txtcom3.Text,
        };

        MessageBox.Show("Student Added Succesfully"); // Advises user the record has succesfully been added
        context.Students.Add(student1); //Adds Student object to DB
        context.SaveChanges(); // Commits change to dDB

        //Clears all textboxes once record has been added
        txtM.Clear();
        txt1.Clear();
        txt2.Clear();
        txtcom1.Clear();
        txtcom2.Clear();
        txtcom3.Clear();
    }
}
```

I am now trying to display what is in the database using the data binding method of dragging the required table, which in this case is student. Onto a grid in xaml.

Now that I've done so it won't display anything in the grid, and it also no longer complies and is telling me that there is ambiguity between my matricno, firstName etc

See error

[image: Error Message]

I just wanted to check if it is something really obvious I have done wrong?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="320" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="517">
        <TabItem Header="Input">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" Margin="0,-1,-14,-7">
                <Button Content="Add Student" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,252,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" Height="26" Click="OnAddNewStudent"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtM" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="148,25,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtcom1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="355,22,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txt1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="148,75,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtcom2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="355,75,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txtcom3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="355,128,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="txt2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="148,128,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
                <Label Content="First Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,75,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" Width="93"/>
                <Label Content="Matriculation No:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" Width="105"/>
                <Label Content="Last Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,128,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="23" Width="93"/>
                <Label Content="Com 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="302,22,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Label Content="Com 2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="302,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Label Content="Com 3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="302,125,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                <Button Content="Purge Database" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="130,252,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" Height="26" Click="OnPurgeDB"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: @nmtuan Parenthesis are optional when using an object initializer.

Comment: thank you, i've learned something :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to look in your xaml file

This error is caused by two items with the same name, remove or rename one of them

```
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="74.778,81.038,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="83.781,135.057,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Comment: Hi Mate, I can't see any duplicates in my XAML, it is quite short. Please see following: http://i.imgur.com/crLefOp.png?1

Comment: I think you need to add Names to you labels they don't seem to have any.

Comment: I see, its complaining that component3 is defined more than once, but I don't see it defined at all in the code you posted.  You could search for component3  Do Control Shift F to find in files in entire solution and search for Component3

Answer (score 0):

Since your student class is a partial class, as i saw in your screenshot [(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZFXc.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZFXc.png) you can look in the file that contains the other part of the class for another declaration with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was because when I had dragged and dropped the new datagrid it had created another file with the variable names, after removing the file it fixed the issue